# How to make generic type variable?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Having generic pydantic model `Localized[T]`, I want to make shortcut type for `Union[T, Localized[T]]`.

I tried to make shortcut like this:

```
MaybeLocalized = TypeVar("MaybeLocalized", bound=Union[T, Localized[T]])
```

but got an error:

```
>> MaybeLocalized[str]
TypeError: 'TypeVar' object is not subscriptable
```

---

nvm, apparently `MaybeLocalized = Union[T, Localized[T]]` works just fine.

Comment: Note that a `TypeVar` is not just a shortcut - it is a generic type factory in its own right, and probably not what you want if you already working with generics. If you just want a shortcut, an alias is the way to go (what you already found to work: `MaybeLocalized = Union[T, Localized[T]]`).